# How to achieve a fast encoding speed from H.265 to H.264 using FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, encoding

So I'm pretty new to video encoding and I'm currently using FFmpeg to change the encoding of a video from H.265 to H.264 so it's suitable for the web.

The current syntax of the command I'm running is

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 51 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac output.mp4
```

I'm currently just trying to get this encoding to run as fast as possible and I'm not sure if there's any additional flags or settings I can tweak to make it run faster.

I've also tried setting the `zerolatency` and `fastdecode` tune to see how that affects it but that didn't do much in terms of speed.

As far as I know, setting the `crf` value and an `ultrafast` preset are basically my options for speeding up the encoding, but are there any additional flags or settings I can use to help speed it up?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't much you can do with your displayed command, but here are some "suggestions":

- [Stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) the audio instead of re-encoding it by changing `-c:a aac` to `-c:a copy`.
- See if a [hardware accelerated](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) encoder such as h264_nvenc instead of libx264 is faster.
- Also check if a hardware decoder is faster.
- Add `-movflags +faststart` output option. This will actually increase the process time by an insignificant amount (compared with the total time), but will let the video begin faster for the viewer.
- Scale the video to half size with the output option `-vf scale=iw/2:-2`
- And the obligatory obnoxiously obvious statement: use a faster CPU or encode on multiple machines.
- Keep it as H.265 and only support Android, Edge, and Safari. Not a terrible solution if you're already providing VP9 (Webm). Then only Internet Explorer will be missing out.

Comment: "Keep it as H.265 and only support Android, Edge, and Safari"

https://caniuse.com/hevc pretty much no one supports h265